# Jobs work works correctly , but no email sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_job (3.0.1) and delayed_job_active_record (0.4.3)
to send emails based on another action when this action is fired

```rb
Delayed::Job.enqueue(MailingJob.new(@auction.id) , 0 , date)
```

and this is the Mailing job

```rb
class MailingJob < Struct.new(:auction_id)
   def perform
     sql = "select a.id , u.fname , u.lname , u.email , p.name
            from auctions a
            join products p on a.product_id = p.id
            join auction_followers af on a.id = af.auction_id
            join users u on af.user_id = u.id
            where a.id = #{auction_id}"
     result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
     result.each(:as => :hash) do |row|
       AuctionMailer.delay.auction_start(row)
     end
   end
 end
```

and this is AuctionMailer

```rb
 class AuctionMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default from: "noreply@yabalashdeals.com"
      def auction_start(data)
         @shared = data
         mail(:to => data['email'], :subject => "Yabalash Auction started")
      end
 end
```

when i run rake jobs:work i get 2 jobs processed at 4.6510 j/s, 0 failed ...
but no emails sent
i made a test function to check auction mailer and it worked correctly

Here is the logs which has no errors

**log/production.log**

```
Sent mail to hesham.kanany@gmail.com (99ms)
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 288ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

**log/delayed_job.log**

```
MaillingJob completed after 0.0035
1 jobs processed at 93.1503 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

**Done** 
Sorry for not posting the solution of this issue i came up with **.deliver()** which must be called if you use **enqueue()** ... Now emails are sent flawlessly

Comment: check your log and paste if you are getting any error?

Comment: can you pull the perform method out of delayed job and try that with the same SQL & parameters?

Comment: I made a test controller/method to check auction mailer and it worked correctly.
and there is a contact us form that send mails and uses MessageMailer which just use **mail()** and it is working perfectly

Comment: My point was, do you know that this works:

sql = "select a.id , u.fname , u.lname , u.email , p.name
            from auctions a
            join products p on a.product_id = p.id
            join auction_followers af on a.id = af.auction_id
            join users u on af.user_id = u.id
            where a.id = #{auction_id}"
     result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
     result.each(:as => :hash) do |row|
       AuctionMailer.delay.auction_start(row)

Comment: yes sure the testing method had the same code & sql

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your delayed job code is wrong.  Try moving that out into a method that you can call from the console.

Specifically, you might want to drop the :as => :hash.

```
def perform
 sql = "select a.id , u.fname , u.lname , u.email , p.name
        from auctions a
        join products p on a.product_id = p.id
        join auction_followers af on a.id = af.auction_id
        join users u on af.user_id = u.id
        where a.id = #{auction_id}"
 result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
 result.each do |row|
   AuctionMailer.delay.auction_start(row)
 end
```

end

Comment: This is the testing code which is not working (without using :as => :hash)

    def perform
          AuctionMailer.auction_start().deliver
    end